# How to requery data in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just started learning Next.js and I'm having some issues with querying data.

I understand that `getInitialProps` is used to query an API and get the data, and it's rendering on the server.

I want a search box where the user search, and as they type, it repeatedly queries the API in a function and stores the results in state, but server-side.

- How can I handle this so it renders on the server and not the client like `getInitialProps` does?
- Is there something special I need to do in my function to make it run on the server?
- Should I just recall `getInitialProps` and pass in the search term?
- What's the best way to get the search query to render on the server and not the client?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this dynamic (as user types in) search on the server. This needs to be handled on UI as [per docs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

> For the initial page load, getInitialProps will execute on the server only.
>   getInitialProps will only be executed on the client when navigating to a
>   different route via the Link component or using the routing APIs.

The only search that will be prerendered on the server is the one that reloads that page.

Example

```
<form action="/search-enpoint">
  <input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" />

  <button>Find</button>
</form>
```

This form will be submitted to `/search-enpoint?search=qwe` that you can catch in [custom server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing)

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

    if (pathname === '/search-enpoint') {
      app.render(req, res, '/index', query);
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
    }
  }).listen(3000, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
  });
});
```

But again this search is not dynamic.

Hope this helps.